# What is the meaning of "All of my parts don't add up to one me" ?

Tags: meaning

In *Before the Devil Knows You're Dead (2007)*, After injected by the drug from Justin, Andy say 
this words to Justin:

> You know, the thing about real estate accounting is that you can, you
>   can  head down the page or across the page, and everything works out. 
>   So, every day, everything adds up. Well, the total is always the sum
>   of its parts. It's clean, it's clear, neat, absolute. But my life, it
>   It doesn't add up. It's Nothing connects to anything else. It's I'm
>   not the sum of my parts. **All of my parts don't add up to one me**, I
>   guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may refer to disconnect or dissociation that Andy feels towards people, events, or parts of his life. He might not feel a strong connection to his experiences (maybe due to drugs?) so he might not feel that they make him whole, i.e. they form his entire identity. Consider when someone says they feel "empty inside". It's the sense that something is missing.